# "No object for D-Bus interface" when mounting with Nautilus

Tags: mount, nautilus, dbus

I have an internal HDD that gives this error when I try to mount either of its two partitions in Nautilus, while my main HDD works fine.

When I use Disks to mount it works but unmounting in Nautilus gives the same error. `mount` works too.

`dmesg` and syslog shows nothing special, so I don't know where to look for the relevant log. I hope someone can provide me some hints on this issue.

Comment: I solved this by going to GParted, choose the the partition, right click it and choose `New UUID`. Apply and done. Sorry for late reply but this question appears on Google.

Comment: @dattutbrus You should really post that as an answer, because it fixed it for me.

Comment: @DanMan This post was last year...

Comment: @dattutbrus Yes, and? It's an answer, so it ought to be posted like one, so that people can upvote it.

Comment: @dattutbrus please add it as an answer. It's still great today. I mean, nobody prefer temporary solutions.

Answer (score 27):

I managed to workaround this issue online by simply restarting the `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor` user service:

```
systemctl --user restart gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
```

After that, mounting disks in Nautilus worked fine.

Comment: While the other methods haven't helped, this one has. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: Thank you! The other answers talking about messing up the UUID for solving an a service glitch issue. unbelievable

Answer (score 24):

Apparently this question appeared on Google and many people are asking me to post an answer, so here it is.

1. First, go to Dash (for Ubuntu) or run `gparted` using superuser, preferrably `gparted-pkexec`.
2. Right click the partition, choose `New UUID`.
3. Click the `Apply` button.

This solution should be permanent until you mess something up, so no worries.

**Update**: Some people claimed that just by having `gparted` refreshing information, the problems are solved. You should try that first, as refreshing UUID screws up `fstab`.

Comment: For me starting `sudo gparted` and just look at the partition was enough, I didn't have to change UUIDs or anything else.

Comment: for me just `e2fsck -f /dev/sda1`

Comment: refreshing gparted worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have temporary solution, try mounting with

`sudo mount /dev/... /mnt/tothisdir`

Or use "Disk" to mount
or any other but not nautilus

Comment: Another workaround is launching gparted and closing it again, weirdly. Taken from here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dbus/+bug/1295927

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should have a look at my [Question & Solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/712547/ubuntu-trusty-14-04-unable-to-mount-partition-not-listed-in-etc-fstab-after-cra) for a detailed analysis ...

In short the `GNOME Virtual File System` or `gvfs` is not working at all.

However `Do Not unmount & remove` the `/run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs` folder as suggested by other posters here (default User ID is 1000).

Find your gvfs folder and [USER ID]

```
$ mount | grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=jean)
$
```

List mount points used by `gvfs`. [NOTE: Since gvfs is not working it should be empty]

```
$ ls -als /run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs
total 0
0 dr-x------  2 jean jean   0 Dec 22 17:42 .
0 drwx------ 10 jean jean 260 Dec 22 17:42 ..
$
```

Check whether the `gvfsd` daemon process is active

```
$ ps axu | grep gvfsd
jean      5993  0.0  0.0 680372  6356 ?        Sl   17:42   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
```

Kill it with the following cmd.

`$ sudo killall -9 gvfsd`

Then relaunch the daemon (process)

`$ sudo /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs`

Well, that's it. It didn't show up straight as I needed to completely shutdown and restart the system (restarting the system without a complete shutdown will not work for me). But right after the system restart, gvfs worked fine and I had access to all partitions / drives within Nemo / Nautilus.

Previously, restarting the system would not solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Unmounting gvfs solved the problem for me:

```
umount -fl /home/user/.gvfs
rm -rf /home/user/.gvfs
```

I found that solution [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=140456)

Answer (score 1):

If botchniaque's fix doesn't work for you, first check the gvfs mountpoint on your system:

```
mount | grep gvfs
```

On Ubuntu 15.10 it was mounted under `/run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs`, so the following commands worked for me:

```
sudo umount -fl /run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs
sudo rm -rf /run/user/[USER ID]/gvfs
```

Answer (score 1):

For me none of the mentioned solutions worked out. Or at least they did not work immediately.

However, after I rebooted the machine, the drive worked.

So I don't know, whether a simple reboot fixed it or the umount/rm -method and a reboot after those.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there was a problem with one partition, so i had to manually mount the other (healhy) one.

1. `sudo parted -l` check the I/O interface p.x. /dev/sda1
2. `sudo /media/mydisk` create mount point
3. `sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0222 /dev/sdb1 /media/mydisk` manually mount the ntfs partition

Answer (score 0):

I've been suffering from this annoying problem for a very long time, having to use the "restart" solution from this answer every day: https://askubuntu.com/a/1128845/1678908

I noticed that (same as other people commented in different forums) it affected some drives but not others. I did not want to be forced to change the UUID of my drives as of the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/860249/1678908

So I investigated further and I found that the problem was in the udisks2 configuration files at the folder /etc/udisks2

There were some old files there and also the udisks2 configuration file was somehow only referring to luks1 and not luks2

So I decided to clean up the udisks2 configuration and it worked! Now I don't have the error, even after rebooting and I did not have to change any UUID.

This is what I did in my Ubuntu 22.04 system:

```
sudo systemctl stop udisks2
sudo mv /etc/udisks2 /etc/udisks2-OLD
sudo systemctl start udisks2
```

After this it seemed to recreate the /etc/udisks2 directory automatically (empty) and nautilus works without any configuration files in there, properly asking for any encrypted drives password without the annoying D-Bus error anymore!

I suppose I could now even improve how udisks2 works by studying the udisks2 configuration files, but just leaving the /etc/udisks2 directory empty seems to work just fine for now.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### I had this problem. And I solve it with these commands.

---

> Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
sudo apt install ntfs-3g
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In my case, when I opened GParted the problem was solved, but upon restarting the computer, the same error persisted. I created this script to open GParted in the background and close it after five seconds. With this, the solution is permanent and I don't have to open GParted every time I log in.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo yourpassword | sudo -S nohup xvfb-run -a /usr/sbin/gparted %f > /tmp/gparted.log 2>&1 &
sleep 5s
echo yourpassword | sudo -S killall gpartedbin
exit 0
```

Replace "yourpassword" with your sudo password and place the script at the system login startup.