# file manager cannot mount btrfs usb disk

Tags: files, usb-drive, btrfs

I have a btrfs usb disk. When I click on the partition, it cannot be mount and an error pops up: `no object for d-bus interface`

But I can use `udisksctl mount -b <dev>` to mount it.

I then click it again to try to unmount it. The same problem pops up. I still can use udsksctl to unmount it. Any idea what to do to fix this?

Comment: nope, btrfs and zfs can be use as general fs. I do not have this problem on KDE.

Comment: We used to have to install BTRFS support and it looks like the package is optional. Is `btrfs-progs` installed? `sudo apt install btrfs-progs` Although, I guess you'd probably get a different error if not.

Comment: If not, udisksctl would not work

Comment: Have you tried [restarting the `gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor` service](https://askubuntu.com/a/1128845/167115)? `systemctl --user restart gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor`

Comment: @mchid if you add an answer I will accept it. It works, thanks! the problem is the udisks2-btrfs is not installed somehow. And udisks2 has nothing to do with udisksctl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `udisks2-btrfs` package as this often has something to do with gvfs and I think udisks is involved with mounting the USB drive.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install udisks2-btrfs
systemctl --user restart gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
```

Comment: no reboot needed just `systemctl --user restart gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor`